# Sql query dynamic variable passing

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I've looked at the documentation in various places to see how to do this, but I haven't had any success. I want to pass in the name of a column into a sql query. I'm using psycopg2 and My most recent attempt was based off of this doc page http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql

Here is my latest attempt, but I get an error `IndexError: tuple index out of range` that points to the `format()` where I'm passing in the parameter.

```
def parse_files(cursor):
    for name in column_names:  
        cursor.execute(
            sql.SQL(
                "select planet_osm_point.{}, count(*) from planet_osm_point group by planet_osm_point.{}"
            ).format(sql.Identifier(name)))
        for row in cursor:
            print(str(row[0]) + str(row[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear by the given documentation, but it looks like I need to pass in a value inside of the `{}` specifying what argument I want to use. In this case it's `{0}`

Answer (score 0):

```
column_names = ['col1', 'col2']
for column in column_names:

    query = sql.SQL('''
        select {0}, count(*)
        from planet_osm_point pop
        group by {0}
    ''').format(sql.Identifier('pop.' + column))

    cursor.execute(query)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print (str(row[0]) + str(row[1]))
```